# How delete data from redis after getting client via soket.io?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, node-redis

Now i pushing data to channel redis everytime, when reload web page and this data is put to stack redis and is displayed here again and again:

```
$rediska->publish('real', 'PHP SENDING'); this is called every reload page

redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
    console.log("Sending from Redis: "+ channel); // here i get real, real, real, real

  });
```

how to control it? i must check if client side get message real, after dont send again this info, and delete data from redis if user click to button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is located just outside the following code:

```
redisClient.on('pmessage', function(pattern, channel, message) {
 console.log("Sending from Redis: "+ channel); // here i get real, real, real, real
});
```

If you call this code each time a new user is connected (on the server-side) it will **add another listener each time a user connects**. So if you reload your page 3 times, your server-side handler will be binded 3 times to the `pmessage` event. That's why you get all those outputs.

To verify this, restart the node server, then load the page, you should see only one "Sending from Redis:", then reload the page again, you should be 2 new console output.

If that's the case just put your `redisClient.on('pmessage'...` code outside of the `.on('connected', ...` handler and it will do the trick.

PS: If this not solve your issue, you should send us more code (both on the server and the client side)